# Shell script to parse incoming dates and print in a standard format

Tags: bash, shell

I need a shells script which could parse incoming date values and print this in a standard format.

Incoming date patterns are:

```
    "yyyyMMdd HHmmss"
    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
    "MMddyyyy:HHmmss"
    "MMddyyyyHHmmssmillisecond"

     20170426 102300
     20170426_102300
     04262017:102300
     0426201710230066
```

Output date pattern :

yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS
20170426_102300

Any idea how to achieve this result in bash. I tried couple of regex for getting result , but that didn't help.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `date` command.  It can take a date/time and provides a lot of very flexible output options.

Comment: Yes but date would take the current date i believe, in this scenario input dates will not always be current date

Comment: Are the listed formats the **only** allowable formats?  That is, you'll never have `20170426:102300`?  Also, please post what you have tried.

Comment: The answers suggest: Use correct regexes and an interpreter of choice (awk, sed, perl, whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the input to **sed**:

```
sed -re 's/([0-9]{8}) ([0-9]{6})/\1_\2/' -e 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4}):?([0-9]{6}).*/\2\1_\3/'
```

Comment: Hi,
is it sed -re or sed -r?

Comment: The `-r` option is needed for extended regular expressions.  The `-e` option specifies the expressions to be used on input.   Using `-re` is just the same as `-r -e`.

Comment: Edited it to collapse two expressions into one.

Answer (score 1):

Is perl acceptable?

```
while (<>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/(\d{8})[ _](\d{6})/) {
        print "$1_$2";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4}):(\d{6})/) {
        print "$2$1_$3";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{6})\d*/) {
        print "$2$1_$3";
    }
}
```

Havn't tested it though...

You could also use it like this:

```
~$ cat data | perl -e 'while (<>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/(\d{8})[ _](\d{6})/) {
        print "$1_$2";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4}):(\d{6})/) {
        print "$2$1_$3";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{6})\d*/) {
        print "$2$1_$3";
    }
}'
```

For your array this may be acceptable:

```
~$ perl -e 'for (@ARGV) {
    if ($_ =~ m/(\d{8})[ _](\d{6})/) {
        print "$1_$2\n";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4}):(\d{6})/) {
        print "$2$1_$3\n";
    } elsif ($_ =~ m/(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{6})\d*/) {
        print "$2$1_$3\n";
    } else { print "$_ does not fit\n"; }
}' "${testdata[@]}"
```

If you don't have perl on your production-environment, you probably want to settle for a `sed` solution.
I suggest the one from Walter A:

```
for t in "${testdata[@]}"; do 
    echo $t |  sed -re 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9:])/\2\1\3/; s/[ _:]//;s/(.{8})(.{6}).*/\1_\2/'; 
done
```

Comment: sorry , only bash scipt.Doe the regex remain the same for shell script?

Comment: Welll yes. Every system that uses PCRE (aka Perl Compatible RegExp) has kind of this syntax.

Comment: @Neethu you are aware that you can use perl also like I've shown in my edited version. If the problem is, that you can't create a seperate file for this.

Comment: Correct. I cannot use a different file with my input data.  all inputs are in an array, which is to be iterated over and converted to yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS

Comment: I tried the regex  you provided to my shell script, but the script not able to parse it.

Comment: I added a version for bash arrays. This may work better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142852/discussion-between-neethu-and-martin-b).

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is a solution using `awk`:

```
awk 'NF==2{print $1"_"$2} $1~"_"{print $1} $1~":"{print gensub(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{6})/, "\\2\\1_\\3", "g", $1)} length($1)==16{print gensub(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{6}).*/, "\\2\\1_\\3", "g", $1)}'
```

Pretty much the same as the `perl` and `sed` examples. Testing and regex replacing.

Answer (score 0):

First make all dates in the format yyyyMMdd

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9:])/\2\1\3/'
```

Next remove the optional character between day and hour

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9:])/\2\1\3/; s/[ _:]//'
```

Change yyyyMMddHHmmss?? into desired format

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9:])/\2\1\3/; s/[ _:]//;s/(.{8})(.{6}).*/\1_\2/'
```

EDIT:
I first tried to show msec, but those were not needed:

```
# INCORRECT SOLUTION
# sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9:])/\2\1\3/; s/[ _:]//; s/$/00/' | cut -c1-16
```

Comment: Hi, @walter A, can you explain what's going on in the first sed command?  I can't quite figure out why it works and doesn't just swap the first four numbers for the next four.  Thanks!

Comment: I get it...  it's looking for a pattern of 4 digits followed by 4 digits followed by either a digit or a colon.  That last bit limits the matching lines to the last two (mmddyyyy) because the first two (yyyymmdd) are 4, 4, and either a space or underscore.  So the first sed command only works on some of the lines -- the ones of the format that need to be switched around.  Thanks!