# BASH_REMATCH to match any regex and provide output

Tags: bash

I am trying to match an input string with regex patterns like below:

```
formatDate(){
 d='[[:digit:]]'
 pattern_a="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d) ($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_b="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)_($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_c="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d):($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_d="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_e="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d$d)"

 unparsable_date="Unable to parse date!"
 TM="TM"

appName="$1"
actionType="$2"
position="$3"
timestamp="$4"

shopt -s nocasematch
    case "$position" in
       "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS"|"YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS"|"YYYYMMDD:HHMMSS"|"YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"|"YYYYMMDDHHMMSSSSS")
            if [[ $timestamp =~ $pattern_a|$pattern_b|$pattern_c|$pattern_d|$pattern_e ]]; then
               formattedDate=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
               formattedTime=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
               formattedTimeStamp="$appName$actionType$formattedDate $appName$actionType$TM$formattedTime"
           else
               formattedTimeStamp=$unparsable_date
            fi
       ;;
    esac

 }
```

If my input matches $pattern_a then the value of `formattedTimeStamp` is populated correctly like below:

input-   `formatDate "appName" "actionType" "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS" "20170426 102300"`

output - `appNameactionType20170426 appNameactionTypeTM102300`

In all other scenarios ie matching with anyother pattern than pattern_a, the code does not produce the correct output,

```
 appNameactionType appNameactionTypeTM 
"date and time is missing here "
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Youre still fighting with the http://stackoverflow.com/q/43663908/632407 ? Why want "pure bash" solution and not using some external programs and reduce the problem to one-line solution?

Comment: sorry,only bash is allowed to use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I replaced the case statement with for loop .It works now .

```
#!/bin/bash
d='[[:digit:]]'
 pattern_a="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d) ($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_b="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)_($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_c="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d):($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_d="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)"
 pattern_e="($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d$d)"
 unparsable_date="Unable to parse date!"

 TM="TM"

appName="appName"
actionType="actionType"
position="YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS"
timestamp="20170426_102300"
declare -a arr=( "$pattern_a" "$pattern_b" "$pattern_c" "$pattern_d" "$pattern_e")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   if [[ $timestamp =~ $i ]]; then
    formattedDate=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    formattedTime=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
    formattedTimeStamp="$appName$actionType$formattedDate $appName$actionType$TM$formattedTime"
    echo $formattedTimeStamp
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can reduce this to a single pattern `($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)[ :_]?($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d$d)?`.